# Was there a British Royal tradition associated with the name Elizabeth?

Tags: united-kingdom, royalty, tradition

My high school history teacher once told me that apperently there was a tradition (superstition?) among the various Royal Families of the United Kingdom that the British Empire would last "from queen Elizabeth to queen Elizabeth", and consequently, royal offspring with any realistic chances of succeeding onto the throne would not be named Elizabeth, so as not to trigger the end of the empire. Is there any evidence of such a tradition?

This seems to fit what has actually happened; it is fair to say that the British Empire lasted from queen Elizabeth I to queen Elizabeth II. Queen Elizabeth II, at birth, was very unlikely to ever become the monarch; she would be very far in the line had king Edward not abdicated. Looking at the [family tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_the_British_royal_family) of the British Royal Family (wikipedia), there are a few Elizabeths in it, but in each case, a younger sibling - except of course Elizabeth II.

But then, I cannot find any reference to such a tradition (it's hard to google, but that was my best shot), and it sounds a bit too good to be true. Is there any evidence of such a tradition, or perhaps that it is made up folklore?

Comment: Technically speaking the British Empire cannot have started with Elizabeth I because 'Great Britain' only came into existence with the Act of Union in 1707 and Elizabeth had been dead for a hundred years by then.

Comment: Royal children are given so many names that even if there was such a superstition, all they would have to do is pick one of the others for their reign name. Example George VI was actually Albert

Comment: @KillingTime I understand your comment as a pure technicality. I think it's fair to say the "British" empire was born under Elizabeth I, even though the Union didn't yet exist, since the defining feature of British Empire was the dominance of (mostly English) colonisers over vast swathes of the world, and that did take off during Elizabeth I's reign

Comment: *I think it's fair to say the "British" empire was born under Elizabeth I* [Citation needed]. With Elizabeth I the British got very few territorial holdings. Navally, they were far behind the Dutch. With claims so flimsy, you could as well said that the British empire did start with William the Conqueror, or Alfred...

Comment: When is this tradition supposed to have come into being? No one spoke of the "British Empire" until the middle of the 18th Century. Also, if the tradition was "from queen Elizabeth to queen Elizabeth", then surely Elizabeth II's mother, Elizabeth, should be counted. She was Queen of the United Kingdom and the Dominions of the British Commonwealth and she was also the last Empress of India (and so has a better claim on being the end of the Empire).

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for [Mythology and Folklore Stack Exchange](https://mythology.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If that was the case, then Queen Elizabeth II could have simply chosen another **regnal name** (as her father and great-uncle did). [Regnal name - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_name#United_Kingdom): *Though most monarchs of the United Kingdom have used their first baptismal name as their regnal name, on three occasions monarchs have chosen a different name.*

Comment: At the time of her birth she was third in line to the throne, after her unmarried uncle and her father.  The most likely scenario was that her uncle would survive, become king, not abdicate and have children, but that he might die without children would not be so improbable that the possibility Eizabeth would one day be Queen could have been ignored.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not defending or proposing this theory. I am asking if there is any evidence for such a tradition, and observing that it is not, a priori, totally nonsensical. That's a very low bar to pass, and it passes it.

Comment: James V, the second most recent monarch to die in Scotland, said in 1542 it came with a lass and it will go with a lass. He was referring to the Stuart Dynasty which came through a daughter of Robert the Bruce and he feared would end since he was dying leaving only a daughter, Mary.   In fact the Stuart Dynasty did end with a lass (woman), but it was Queen Anne 172 years later. But could a garbled version of this be behind your teacher's saying?

Comment: It has also been said that if the ravens leave the Tower (of London) the Empire will fall. As far as I know the ravens are still there - though I gather they did feed them rather well during WW2 - despite food rationing. Personally I had never previously heard of the superstition around the name Elizabeth.

Comment: LOL! If I were the first superstitious person on the matter I would tell the British Empire lasts from Victoria to Victoria. But joking apart, there were **a few** female heir apparents in the whole history of the British Empire. So it's understandable that there were just two Elizabeths in the line to succeed. The superstiton makers just used people's naiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collating some of the comments into an answer:

- Over a few days, no answer came forward confirming the existence of such tradition, or of something closely related; while lack of evidence is not evidence, this suggest there isn't a widely known tradition of this kind.
- Some of the terms are a bit ambiguous; "British Empire" as a term didn't come to be until 18th century, it is not clear-cut that Elisabeth I was the founder what later became the "British Empire" - further casting doubt on the existence of such a tradition.
- Elizabeth II, at birth, was not *that* fact removed from the line. Her uncle and his future offspring were ahead of her, but for example should he die childless she would be in the running.
- Most direct suggestion, from user @davidlol, mentions James V saying "it came with a lass and it will go with a lass", referring to the Stuart dynasty. Nothing to do with the empire or women named Elizabeth, but could conceivably be mutated into my teacher's suggestion.

Comment: James meant Mary Stewart but it was actually Queen Anne.